# How can I make autoplot.varprd work with zoo objects

Tags: r, ggfortify

```
library(vars)
library(ggfortify)
library(zoo)
data(Canada, package = 'vars')
Canada <- zoo(Canada)
#autoplot.zoo works fine with zoo objects
autoplot(Canada)
d.var <- vars::VAR(Canada, p = 3, type = 'const')
#however autoplot.varprd does not work with zoo objects
autoplot(stats::predict(d.var, n.ahead = 50), conf.int = TRUE)
```

This is the error I get above:

> autoplot(stats::predict(d.var, n.ahead = 50), conf.int = TRUE)
>       Error in get.dtindex.continuous(model$model$y, length = nrow(fcst[[1]]),  : 
>         Failed to convert ts object index to date

How can I make autoplot.varprd work with zoo objects and show the dates?

If I start from a zoo object and convert it to ts then autoplot.varprd will work but will show numbers instead of dates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid using ggfortify by converting the prediction to a zooreg object and then invoking `autoplot.zoo`:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- predict(d.var, n.ahead = 50)
freq <- frequency(Canada)
z <- zooreg(data.frame(lapply(p$fcst, "[", TRUE, 1)), end(Canada) + 1/freq, freq = freq)
autoplot.zoo(z) + scale_x_yearqtr() + facet_free()
```

Note that if ggfortify is NOT loaded then `autoplot.zoo` can optionally be shortened to `autoplot`.